# Is it possible to "sign in with a capable Google app" on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, google-signin

The [GIDSignIn Class](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#method-detail) documentation says that GIDSignIn "provides single sign-on via a capable Google app if one is installed".

However, the same document also says for "checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled":

> DEPRECATED: this method always calls back with NO on iOS 9 or above.
>
> Do not use this method. Checks if a Google app to handle sign in requests is installed on the user's device on iOS 8 or below.

After a lot of searching, I can't make it work - despite URL Schemes, allowSignInWithWebView/Browser, ...

So my question is simple:

- Should it be *possible* to "sign in with a capable Google app" on iOS 9 ?
  and/or
- Is there any app out there that supports this? (and if you know how, that's a bonus :)